# AMP nested-accordion add text

Tags: amp-html

I want to add some text at the top of nested-accordion section as follow:

```
<amp-accordion disable-session-states>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>Bunch of content.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion"> ADD TEXT HERE
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
        <p>Bunch of content.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
        <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
```

The problem is I try to change the color/ font size by h1 , the accordion will not work.
Please help!

Comment: change the color of h4

Comment: "ADD TEXT HERE" not in h4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-accordion" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-accordion-0.1.js"></script>
<title>Hello, AMPs</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.ampproject.org/article-metadata.html" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
<script type="application/ld+json">
      {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "NewsArticle",
        "headline": "Open-source framework for publishing content",
        "datePublished": "2015-10-07T12:02:41Z",
        "image": [
          "logo.jpg"
        ]
      }
    </script>
<style amp-boilerplate>
body {
    -webkit-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    -moz-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    -ms-animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both;
    animation: -amp-start 8s steps(1, end) 0s 1 normal both
}
@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start {
from {
visibility:hidden
}
to {
visibility:visible
}
}
@-moz-keyframes -amp-start {
from {
visibility:hidden
}
to {
visibility:visible
}
}
@-ms-keyframes -amp-start {
from {
visibility:hidden
}
to {
visibility:visible
}
}
@-o-keyframes -amp-start {
from {
visibility:hidden
}
to {
visibility:visible
}
}
@keyframes -amp-start {
from {
visibility:hidden
}
to {
visibility:visible
}
}
</style>
<noscript>
<style amp-boilerplate>
body {
    -webkit-animation: none;
    -moz-animation: none;
    -ms-animation: none;
    animation: none
}
</style>
</noscript>
<style amp-custom>
amp-accordion section[expanded] .show-more {
    display: none;
}
amp-accordion section:not([expanded]) .show-less {
    display: none;
}
.nested-accordion { color:#F32225; }
.nested-accordion h4 {
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    color:#000;
}
.nested-accordion p { color:#000; }
amp-accordion#hidden-header section[expanded] h4 {
    border: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <h4>Welcome to the mobile web</h4>
  <amp-accordion disable-session-states>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 1</h4>
    <p>Bunch of content.</p>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h4>Section 2</h4>
    <amp-accordion class="nested-accordion"> ADD TEXT HERE
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.1</h4>
        <p>Bunch of content.</p>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h4>Nested Section 2.2</h4>
        <p>Bunch of more content.</p>
      </section>
    </amp-accordion>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```